# Issue with an array blank echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

Hey working on a small project but I seem to be having a problem with a specific part of my code.

The first part works beautifully and displays products within a product category. 
http://mkiddr.com/phptests/shopping/category.php?id=2

However the issue seems to be having the category description to show, which is derived from a separate query into its own array. I have used

```
echo(mysqli_num_rows($result2));
```

This seems to count the correct amounts of rows from the query, indicating the SQL is working perfectly.

I would appreciate help on this I am a complete needbe and I have patched and edited this code to my needs (supplied by university). P.S I am aware there are vulnerabilities within security.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conn.php";
include "header.php";

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
$CategoryID = $_GET['id'];
$q="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";
$d="SELECT `Desc` FROM ProductCategories WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";

$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
$result2 = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$d) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<div>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<p><a href='product.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></p>";
}
echo "</div>";
mysqli_free_result($result);

//Description
echo(mysqli_num_rows($result2)); //Test SQL

echo "<div>";
while ($myResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    echo "<p>".$myResult[0]."</p>";
}
echo "</div>";
}
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're fetching wrong:

```
while ($myResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                                ^^^^^--- produces a non-numerically keyed array
```

You probably want

```
echo $myResult['name_of_field']
```

or

```
mysqli_fetch_row($result2)
             ^^^--returns a numerically keyed array.
```

instead.